# True current procedure and cost of extending Cambodia tourist visa in person?

Tags: visa-extensions, cambodia, phnom-penh

I can find lots of pages recommending extending your Cambodian visa through a travel agent, hostel, guesthouse, hotel, or even supermarket or bike shop.

**But** all seem to merely repeat hearsay about it being too hard or too much hassle to do it directly and say the fee the agents etc charge is "small". Also they give a wide range of different prices from $15 up to I believe at least $45. My guesthouse quoted me something above $50 from memory.

I'm seeking the true actual current details of doing a visa extension in Phnom Penh on one's own, just to have the facts available for any reasons travellers might want.

I personally don't mind getting to the airport and back a couple of times and will do it and report back here. But I would appreciate any link or reference that's either official or a recent story of traveller who did it.

Comment: From my experience, it's extremely simple to get the extension - you just pay the visa fee. The variance in prices is simply market variation of third party visa agency fees. I'll answer when I have an authoritative source.

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee: You did it yourself in the office near the airport in PP?

Comment: Yeah you just fill out a really simple form (keep a photo in case they ask; they shouldn't). Can't find the latest official figure for cost of visa extension (loads of third party sites).

Comment: How long ago and did you have to return another day to pick it up?

Comment: Three years ago now. Got it on the same day but that may be because I introduced the visa guy to a new Bollywood song. (You won't believe the amount of free stuff and/or speeded up processes I get when travelling abroad because of Bollywood. I hate Bollywood.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I walked from the hostel zone near the Independence Monument to **the immigration office, opposite the airport** (a long way, not recommended for people less crazy than me).

[image: Visa office at Cambodian Immigration, Phnom Penh]

Apparently a tuk-tuk would be about $9/$10 but we discovered there is a comfortable air-conditioned **city bus to the airport for KHR 1,500** (37 and a half cents!) which runs along Confederation de la Russie from the Night Market. This is new since late 2014.

At 2pm, the very friendly staff gave me a **single-sided single-page form** which was simple to fill out. One passport photo was required, which I had with me. The office was not busy, just a few others.

After handing in the form I had to wait 15 to 20 minutes for the application to be lodged, then I had to pay **USD 30** for which I was given a receipt. I was told to **come back in seven days to pick up my passport**. This might not be the usual length of time since Chinese New Year is this week, [but there are no Cambodian public holidays](http://www.acledabank.com.kh/kh/eng/md_publicholiday_2015.php).

The office is open from 8am to 4.30pm with a lunch break between 12 noon and 2pm.

As mentioned on many forums, tourist visas can be extended one time only for one month only.

Much of the other information on most forums seems to be FUD. The staff were very friendly and happy and helpful. I wasn't given the runaround. There was no apparent bureaucracy or complicated processes. The form is simple to fill out. Everything is clear. There were no bribes or mysterious extra fees. The fee is $30 (my guesthouse quoted me $45 or $46 I believe.)

So including a tuk-tuk ride there and back to apply and another ride there and back to pick up the passport could be up to 4 x $10, so cheaper to get an agent to do it. But if you take the city bus it only adds up to $1.50 for all four trips. Another option is to go on a motorbike taxi, which might only be $2 per trip.

If you're a traveller on a tight budget it's definitely cheaper to do it yourself by taking the bus. If you're an expat with an income the extra USD $15 might be nothing to you.

**The only factor remaining could be the processing time. At this point I don't know if it always takes seven days. I'll double check how long the guesthouse says it takes through them.**

Not having your passport for this one week may make it tricky to change accommodation or do a trip while you're waiting as most hotels and guesthouses want your passport at check-in. I noted down my passport and visa numbers, so hopefully this will be enough for checking in.

---

Seven days after applying, I returned to the Visa Service office a few minutes after 2pm as requested.

This time they were a little busier but still very happy and polite. I sat and waited in the air conditioning I badly needed until my name was called and I was handed my passport with a new full-page visa of a different colour with departure date one calendar month later than my original visa (not 30 days later - it's February). There were no additional fees or hassles.

Since they were busy and the place was being closed for some high level meeting I did not have the chance to ask the prices of extensions of different durations.

Comment: I fear my answer is very long and rambly so feel free to suggest edits or do some readability improvements.

Comment: Can you tell us where in the airport (?) the "visa office" is located?

Comment: The visa office is just opposite the airport on the main road "Confederation de la Russie", and stands out well on Google maps.

Comment: Ijust applied for a visa  extension, it is gonna take 7 days for it to be ready so that seems to be the standard processing time.

Answer (score 7):

10 April 2015.
The Immigration / Visa office quoted me the following extension rates:

1 month - $30
3 months - $60
6 months - $100

They were very particular in wanting to see my rental contract and would not give me a visa that extended past it.

Also my wait time is 3 weeks due to Khmer New Year

Comment: How many months were you asking for? Are you on a tourist visa?

Comment: I was asking for a 6 month extension. Had to update my rental agreement to get it.
I'm on a business or regular visa (E), so unlimited extensions are possible. I requested 6 months because that is the shortest that has multiple entry options.
Tourist visas may be extended for a maximum of one month.

Comment: Yes I roughly knew that. I'm expecting that's why your extension is more difficult than mine was so it's relevant information.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. Thank you for your original post. You saved me at least $60, probably more. I also tried the bus. It was pretty nice, better than some in BKK.

Comment: No worries mate. You can buy me a beer next time we're in the same town (-;